# ScrollTop inside css scrollbar (overflow-y: auto)

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I am working on this accordion. Here, you can see list of accordion inside a scrollbar. Here, whenever we click on heading, it should scroll to top so that heading and text is visible properly. I have tried many things but it is not working inside scrollbar. Although code is perfectly outside where we don't have scrollbar. Here is the fiddle I have created. Hope anyone help.

https://jsfiddle.net/t2fpeq0d/

```js
$('.accordion-block-heading').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $parent = $this.parent();
  var $position = $this.position().top;
  console.log($position);
  $this.next().stop().slideToggle();

  $('.site-accordion').animate({
    scrollTop: $this.offset().top
  }, 2000);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML-


<!-- Site Accordion -->
<ol class="site-accordion mt-30">
  <!-- Accordion Block -->
  <li class="accordion-block">
    <h3 class="accordion-block-heading">Title question goes here lorem ipsum dolor?</h3>
    <p class="accordion-block-content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </li>
  <!-- Accordion Block -->
  <!-- Accordion Block -->
  <li class="accordion-block`enter code here`">
    <h3 class="accordion-block-heading">Title question goes here lorem ipsum dolor?</h3>
    <p class="accordion-block-content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </li>
  <!-- Accordion Block -->
  <!-- Accordion Block -->
  <li class="accordion-block" id="test">
    <h3 class="accordion-block-heading">Title question goes here lorem ipsum dolor?</h3>
    <p class="accordion-block-content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </li>
  <!-- Accordion Block -->
  <!-- Accordion Block -->
  <li class="accordion-block">
    <h3 class="accordion-block-heading">Title question goes here lorem ipsum dolor?</h3>
    <p class="accordion-block-content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </li>
  <!-- Accordion Block -->
  <!-- Accordion Block -->
  <li class="accordion-block">
    <h3 class="accordion-block-heading">Title question goes here lorem ipsum dolor?</h3>
    <p class="accordion-block-content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </li>
  <!-- Accordion Block -->
  <!-- Accordion Block -->
  <li class="accordion-block">
    <h3 class="accordion-block-heading">Title question goes here lorem ipsum dolor?</h3>
    <p class="accordion-block-content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </li>
  <!-- Accordion Block -->
  <!-- Accordion Block -->
  <li class="accordion-block last-block" style="padding-bottom: 0">
    <h3 class="accordion-block-heading">Title question goes here lorem ipsum dolor?</h3>
    <p class="accordion-block-content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </li>
  <!-- Accordion Block -->
</ol>
<!-- Site Accordion -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Position](http://api.jquery.com/position/), like this:

```
$("body, html").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#accordian-block-1").position().top
});
```

Obviously, you need to add a unique id to each element.

I would recommend using .attr() to get the ID of whatever heading is clicked, and then parse the heading ID into a number. You can then use this number to supply the ID of the desired element/accordian block to scroll to.

Comment: Please check again. My CSS was not updated there. Because of that there was no scrollbar. Now I have added it and you see, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to position the `site-accordion` element to top of the clicked accordion. You should be positioning the document body to the accordion element like this :

```
$([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
    scrollTop: $position
}, 2000);
```

Check this updated JS [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fsgdL7kt/1/)

Pardon me for any spell errors, replying from my mobile device.

Comment: Please check again. My CSS was not updated there. Because of that there was no scrollbar. Now I have added it and you see, it is not working.

Comment: Hi Nishant, where exactly have you added your CSS? I'm unable to see any CSS in the fiddle present in your question? Did you create a new fiddle? If yes, can you please provide the link of it?